# Defining classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have been reading up on object-oriented JavaScript. This is a link that I have been reading, *[Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)*. However, I have also been reading the book *[Practical CakePHP Projects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143021578X)*. I am trying to figure out why do they use class to define the class? From what I have read, you are supposed to define classes using the `function` keyword. The code below is an example from the book. Were the authors just wrong or is there something that I am missing?

```
var TravelMapprManager = Class.create({

    //Constructor
    initialize: function(map_container) {
        this.map_container = map_container;

        //Start the map.
        Event.observe(window, 'load', this.displayMap.bind(this));

        //Observe the map buttons.
        Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', this.initObservers.bind(this));
    },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Class` is not a keyword.  It is a namespace for library code that contains the `create` function which sets up the constructor (the function you mentioned) and the `prototype` for you.

You can read more about it in the documentation for this particular library : http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Class/create/

> `Class.create` creates a class and returns a constructor function for instances of the class. Calling the constructor function (typically as part of a `new` statement) will invoke the class's `initialize` method.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if they are using some library in the book that you are reading? That might answer your direct question.

Below is a very quick example (hopefully correct as I've not tested it, but it should give you the idea) of what you are trying to do (Just found this which might be helpful: http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class)

```
function TravelMapprManager() {
}

TravelMapprManager.prototype.initialize = function(mapContainer) {
    this.mapContainer = mapContainer;

    ...
};

var mappr = new TravelMapprManager();
mappr.initialize(...);
```

Comment: The phpied article gets slated in the comments, which leave the whole thing more confusing than helpful